# How can use Micronaut + Zuul + Consult with Token Propagation?

Tags: netflix-zuul, micronaut

I'm building a microservice system using `Micronaut` + `Consul` + `Token Propagation`, so now I want add a API Gateway and my first choice is Netflix Zuul, but Zuul proxies the request using a Netty and Micronaut is a server built on netty too, how can a manage this? if I use ad hoc Zuul (without Micronaut) I loose `Token Propagation`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since token propagation is just about forwarding headers downstream you can configure Zuul to do so. See https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__router_and_filter_zuul.html#_cookies_and_sensitive_headers

Comment: works wonderful. In front of Micronaut service I implemented Spring Cloud + Zuul + Consul. But if we've had some *started* to Micronaut+Zuul will be better